# Entity Framework query in select top 2 from other entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I would like to archive this query through Entity Framework environment in my ASP.NET MVC project.

This is what my query should execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents
WHERE CREATEDATE IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 FORMONTH
    FROM DocHistory 
    WHERE FORMONTH < GETDATE()
    ORDER BY FORMONTH DESC
)
```

How can I do this in Entity Framework?

```
var result = from d in Documents
             where d.CREATEDATE ???
```

Best regards,

Veasna

Answer (score 1):

OK so breaking this down into it's two parts.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 FORMONTH
FROM DocHistory 
WHERE FORMONTH < GETDATE()
ORDER BY FORMONTH DESC
```

This becomes

```
DocHistory.Where(dh => dh.FORMONTH < DateTime.Now)
          .OrderByDescending(dh => dh.FORMONTH)
          .Take(2);
```

So we now have the two months

```
Documents.Where(doc=> DocHistory.Where(dh => dh.FORMONTH < DateTime.Now)
                                .OrderByDescending(dh => dh.FORMONTH)
                                .Take(2)
                                .Select(q => q.FORMONTH)
                                .Contains(doc.CREATEDATE.Month))
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation what this does and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep in simple. First get the 2 dates and then the documents you want. Like this:

```
var dates = DocHistory.Where(dh => dh.FORMONTH < DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(FORMONTH).Take(2);
var results = Documents.Where(d => dates.Contains(dates));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's describe inner query:

```
DocHistory.Select(dh => dh.FORMONTH)
          .Where(dt => dt < DateTime.Now)
          .Distinct()
          .OrderByDescending()
          .Take(2)
```

Then full query will be:

```
Documents.Where(d => DocHistory.Select(dh => dt.FORMONTH)
                               .Where(dt => dt < DateTime.Now)
                               .Distinct()
                               .OrderByDescending()
                               .Take(2)
                               .Contains(d.CREATED));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
var date = DateTime.Now;

from d in db.Documents
where ( from t in db.DocHistory
        where FORMMONTH < date
        select FORMMONTH).OrderByDescending()
                         .Distinct()
                         .Take(2).Contains(d.CREATEDATE)
select d;
```

hope this will help you